# RLMRealm(path:) Argument labels '(path:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift3, realm

I just tried to install the latest version of Realm (2.1.0) for Swift 3 and I'm getting an error on this line: let realm = RLMRealm(path: databasePath) - DataManager.swift:258:21: Argument labels '(path:)' do not match any available overloads
The declaration of the argument is here:
    var databasePath : String

I know that swift 3 is requiring label for the first argument, but I've looked everywhere for the replacement and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`+ [RLMRealm realmWithPath:]` was an API that was deprecated and entirely removed from Realm many months ago. It was replaced with `+ [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:]`, where you supply an `RLMRealmConfiguration` object with the file path to the target file set in its `fileURL` property.

```
let configuration = RLMRealmConfiguration.defaultConfiguration()
configuration.fileURL = URL(path: databasePath)
let realm = RLMRealm(configuration: configuration)
```

On a side note, unless you've got a specific reason for using the Objective-C version of Realm in Swift, I highly recommend you use [the native Swift version of Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) instead. That one should be a lot easier, and feel a lot more natural in Swift 3. :)

Comment: Thanks TiM, I'm new to the project and picking up where some dev left off 6 months ago. I suspect I have some serious housekeeping to do since the project has scads of Realm.h and other stuff still in it.

Comment: Thanks TiM, I'm new to the project and picking up where some dev left off 6 months ago. I suspect I have some serious housekeeping to do since the project has scads of Realm.h and other stuff still in it. That said, I did find a temporary work around for this which is because the argument to RLMRealm(_:) is looking for a url rather than a string. So the workaround was: var databasePath : URL, Then let realm = RLMRealm(url: databasePath). But I suppose all of that will change if I follow the recommendation to use the native Swift version of Realm instead.